# Complex SQL Query w/ Multiple Tables

Tags: sql

I have the following tables in my database:

**Products**

```
ID_PRODUCT
PRODUCTNAME
PRICE
```

**Customers**

```
ID_CUSTOMER
NAME
```

**Orders**

```
ID_ORDER
CUSTOMER_ID
PRODUCT_ID
QUANTITY
```

How would I select all the customers who ordered 4 products or more?

Comment: It is not complex. It is UPPERCASE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you mean, "How to select all customer ids who ordered four or more different products?", then you would use the following:

```
select customer_id
from orders
group by customer_id
having count(distinct product_id) >= 4
```

If you just want four or more product lines on orders, then you would drop the "distinct" from the "count".

If you want more customer information, then you can join this to the customers table to get the name (and so on).

Comment: Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression count(distinct product_id) >= 4

Comment: What database are you using?  This is standard SQL syntax and should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from Customers as c
where (select count(*) from Orders as o where o.CUSTOMER_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID) > 3
```

Comment: db asks to enter parameter value c.CUSTOMER_ID

Comment: Mmm, there are no parameters in this query.